# Hamilton's rule: When to change the equation?

Tags: evolution, ethology, behaviour

So, in class, my teacher gave two examples of using hamilton's rule. Let b= 4 and c=2.5.

The first was whether altruism would evolve between two diploid full siblings given these values. Since r=1/2, the equation was (0.5)(4)-2.5.

The second question was the same but from a daughter to her mother. He used (1/2)(4)- (1/2)(2.5).

I was confused as to why the teacher outlined this difference. I know that it has to do with the asymmetrical and symmetrical relatedness concept but don't know the details.

Would it continue to apply to grandparents and aunts/uncles as well?